# modulus of continuity of a family of functions

Tags: real-analysis

Let $(X, d)$ be a compact metric space,$\forall  n\in N$,  $g_n:X\rightarrow X$ be a homeomorphism and $f:X\rightarrow X$ an uniform continuous.

The modulus of a continuity of a uniform continuous map $f:(X, d)\rightarrow (X, d)$ is given by 
$$\omega(\delta, f):= \sup _{d(x, y)<\delta}d(f(x), f(y)).$$
Here is my question: $\omega(\omega(\frac{1}{n}, g_n), f)\rightarrow 0$ as  $n\rightarrow \infty$

Comment: Without some equicontinuity assumption on $g_n$ it's not true. Consider $X=[0,1]$ and $g_n(x)=x^{1/n}$.

Comment: Dear Del , Thanks for your reply, Suppose  $\{g_n\}$ is a sequence of equicontinuous homeomorphism, Have can I prove it?

Comment: If $g_n$ are uniformly equicontinuous, by definition they have the same modulus of continuity. Now it suffices to use that $\lim_{\delta\to 0}\omega(\delta)=0$ for the modulus of continuity $\omega$ of any function.